# How to fix Ogre3d segfault with std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance?

Tags: c++, ogre

I'm working on a 3d music visualizer using Ogre3d, basically it's a spectrum analizer, a lot like the old xmms plugin:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6NKBiwYN24

It works well, the bars are drawn and updated, there are no framerate issues, but it crashes randomly. Sometimes it can run without problems, finish the song, other times it crashes instantly, other times the music just stops, without a crash.

Here is the source code for the main class :

https://github.com/balazsbela/OgreVisualizer/blob/master/src/VisualizerApplication.cpp#L221

Also the crashes seem to happen less often when I display the framerate overlay from Ogre samples. Would limiting the framerate help ?

The crashes are seemingly random. Is it a performance issue ?

Please help me out, I'm quite lost on this one, I also posted on Ogre3d forums but I received no responses.

http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=63207

I also tried stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050147/how-to-fix-ogre3d-segfault-with-std-rb-tree-insert-and-rebalance

Backtrace:

```
balazsbela@darknet:~/workspace/OgreVisualizer/Release$ gdb OgreVisualizer core
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2-debian
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i486-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/balazsbela/workspace/OgreVisualizer/Release/OgreVisualizer...done.
[New Thread 17705]
[New Thread 17702]
[New Thread 17703]
[New Thread 17700]
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.1...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/local/lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libfftw3.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libfftw3.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libSDL_sound-1.0.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libSDL_sound-1.0.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libOIS-1.2.0.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libOIS-1.2.0.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libm-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/libgcc_s.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libpthread-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libv4l1.so.0...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/local/lib/libv4l1.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libSM.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libSM.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libICE.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libICE.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libX11.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libX11.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXext.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXext.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXt.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXt.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXaw.so.7...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXaw.so.7
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libdl-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.42.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.42.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.42.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.42.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libfreeimage.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libfreeimage.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libzzip-0.so.13...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libzzip-0.so.13
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libz.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libz.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libsmpeg-0.4.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libsmpeg-0.4.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libmikmod.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libmikmod.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libvorbis.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libvorbis.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libvorbisfile.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libvorbisfile.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libogg.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libogg.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/sse2/libspeex.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/sse2/libspeex.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libasound.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libasound.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/librt.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/librt-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/librt.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libdirectfb-1.2.so.9...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libdirectfb-1.2.so.9
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libfusion-1.2.so.9...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libfusion-1.2.so.9
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libdirect-1.2.so.9...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libdirect-1.2.so.9
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libvga.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libvga.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/ld-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libv4l2.so.0...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/local/lib/libv4l2.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/libuuid.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libuuid.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXmu.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXmu.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXpm.so.4...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXpm.so.4
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libmng.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libmng.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libopenjpeg.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libopenjpeg.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/libpng12.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libpng12.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libIlmImf.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libIlmImf.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libImath.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libImath.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libHalf.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libHalf.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libIex.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libIex.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libIlmThread.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libIlmThread.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/libx86.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libx86.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libv4lconvert.so.0...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/local/lib/libv4lconvert.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXau.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXau.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/liblcms.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/liblcms.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/local/lib/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libGL.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libGLcore.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libGLcore.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_compat.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libnss_compat-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_compat.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libnsl-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_nis.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libnss_nis-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_nis.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_files.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libnss_files-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_files.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/sse2/libspeexdsp.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/sse2/libspeexdsp.so.1
Core was generated by `./OgreVisualizer'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb6dc563d in std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&) ()
   from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6dc563d in std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&) ()
   from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0xb73bb3c2 in std::_Rb_tree<Ogre::Node*, Ogre::Node*, std::_Identity<Ogre::Node*>, std::less<Ogre::Node*>, Ogre::STLAllocator<Ogre::Node*, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, Ogre::Node* const&) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.1
#2  0xb73b5a52 in _M_insert_unique (this=0xb6157ea0, child=0xb616aff8, forceParentUpdate=false) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h:1182
#3  insert (this=0xb6157ea0, child=0xb616aff8, forceParentUpdate=false) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_set.h:411
#4  Ogre::Node::requestUpdate (this=0xb6157ea0, child=0xb616aff8, forceParentUpdate=false)
    at /home/balazsbela/Downloads/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreNode.cpp:805
#5  0xb73b6a40 in Ogre::Node::needUpdate (this=0xb616aff8, forceParentUpdate=92)
    at /home/balazsbela/Downloads/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreNode.cpp:789
#6  0xb73b5038 in Ogre::Node::setScale (this=0x1825c, scale=...) at /home/balazsbela/Downloads/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreNode.cpp:638
#7  0x0805d306 in VisualizerApplication::adjustNodes (this=0x9cd4808) at ../src/VisualizerApplication.cpp:236
#8  0xb6e867f0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0
#9  0xb6e8719a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0
#10 0xb6ed9b0d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#11 0xb6ee185e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#12 0xb6f2e0bd in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#13 0xb6bc7955 in start_thread (arg=0xb198ab70) at pthread_create.c:300
#14 0xb6ca6e7e in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:130
(gdb)
```

Ogre.log: http://pastie.org/1581790

Comment: You should really have flagged your question for a moderator to migrate it here rather than reposting.

Answer (score 3):

Standard C++ containers do not offer guarantees of threadsafety, and I don't think OgreNodes do either. You're probably adjusting the node at the same time Ogre is doing something with it in a different thread.

You also have a double delete and leave behind a stale pointer in ~VisualizerApplication. Fix it by not making it a singleton. Just... don't use singletons. [Ever.](http://www.google.com/search?q=singleton+pattern+sucks)

Comment: Lots of (Person) Singleton hate in this world. Is, http://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/singleton-considered-stupid what you wanted to point him to?

Comment: I really meant it to be a shorthand link to every anti-singleton essay (there are plenty). It's somewhat ironic how many people are named "Singleton".

Comment: I removed the Singleton, removed the separate thread for drawing, but I still get the crash. https://github.com/balazsbela/OgreVisualizer/blob/master/src/VisualizerApplication.cpp   I use the semaphore to make sure that the visualize function is not called twice simultaneously, i.e. before it finished for the previous dataset. It should be serialized now, but I still get the crash. Any ideas ?

Comment: You've missed the problem entirely. You're still updating nodes in a thread while Ogre is trying to do something with them. It doesn't matter how many locks are in your own code - which should be zero - you have to have some sort of synchronization with Ogre.